# Connecting with only JTAG

Tags: arm, jtag, prototyping, texas-instruments

I've been wanting try out new microcontrollers and microprocessors other than the very mainstream Arduino and similar. So I want to start by making a inexpensive test board with a minimal test of peripherals - just to see that I can get it working. Can most devices run with just a JTAG connection? Would this be ideal to begin learning a new device?

I've seen a lot development boards on the market, but they're expensive and cluttered with circuits. I'd really rather just start simple so I can understand everything that's going on.

If it makes a differences, I'm interested in testing TI ARM products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the best way to learn about a new device is to buy already made board and experiment with various peripherals, one peripheral at a time. Then you can design your own board with only the peripherals you need. Once you have your own board, you can quickly bring it up using the code you have already developed.
To answer your question, most micro-controllers just need to have the clock pins, and power pin connected to bring them up. Just be aware, ARM micro-controllers are quite complex compared to say Atmel AVRs or PICs. Refer to the datasheet for the ARM device you are interested to make sure all power pins are connected properly as there are multiple power pins (Vcc, Vccio, Vccad, etc). Don’t forget about bypass caps and some power pins may require power planes on the board.